# How do I create an insertAfter function for a doubly linked list c++

Tags: c++, nodes, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to create an insertAfter function where it accepts a value by reference and then inserts that value after the current node. I am unsure how to implement the code.

Below is the header file and what I have tried but it does not compile.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class DoublyLinkedList {
public:
    DoublyLinkedList();
    ~DoublyLinkedList();
    void append (const string& s);
    void insertBefore (const string& s);
    void insertAfter (const string& s);
    void remove (const string& s);
    bool empty();
    void begin();
    void end();
    bool next();
    bool prev();
    bool find(const string& s);
    const std::string& getData() const;
private:
    class Node
    {
    public:
        Node();
        Node(const string& data);
        ~Node();
        Node* next;
        Node* prev;
        string* data;
    };
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
    Node* current;
};

void DoublyLinkedList::insertAfter(const string& s)
{
    // Node *temp, *var;
    //var=(Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        append(s);
    }
    temp->data=current;
}

void DoublyLinkedList::append(const string& s)
{
    //create a new Node
    current = new Node(s);
    if (this->empty())//check if it is empty or not
    {
        this->head = this->tail = current;
    }else{
        //append to tail
        current->prev = tail;
        tail->next = current;
        tail = current;
    }
}

#endif
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve] by including definition of `append` function and initialization of `temp`.

Comment: This code is just wrong on many levels. This is not how a linked list should look. But, to answer the question asked, there is a very important parameter missing from both `insertBefore()` and `insertAfter()` - the target `Node` to insert before/after! So start by fixing that. You already know how to insert a new node after a given node, you do it in `append()`. Similar logic applies when inserting before a node instead of after it, just swap the assignments of `prev` and `next`. If you still can't figure it out, *draw it out* on paper. And then throw away this code and use `std::list` instead

Comment: Please include definition of all the dependencies including `empty()` etc. Also, Can you please explain why do you need `current` as data member of class and why `temp->data=current;` statement is required?

Comment: Mention the compilation error that you are getting.

Answer (score -1):

-Create a new node and store the data passed in. Set the current pointer to head.

```
Node * newNode = new Node(s);
current=head;
```

-You must traverse over the LinkedList using a loop which checks the values of each node using 2 pointers, one which trails behind the one that checks the node values.

```
while(current->data != insertAfter- 
>data)
{
current=current->next;}
```

-Once the proper node is found with current, the loop should stop. Set the new node's next pointer to the insertAfter's next pointer, and the prev pointer to the insertAfter node.

```
newNode->next = insertAfterNode->next;
newNode->prev = insertAfterNode;
```

-You then set current's next pointer to the node you'd like to insert.

```
current->next = newNode;
```

Also, be sure to add each potential case. If it is the tail that was inserted after, be sure to set the tail pointer to newNode and same if it is inserted at the head. After traversing with the loop, put:

```
if(tail->data==current->data)
{
    tail = newNode;
}

if(head->data==current->data)
{
    head=newNode;
}
```

Edit: because this is a doubly LinkedList, the prev pointer can be implemented in place of trailCurrent, which is not needed at all.

Comment: I think you should try to use the code posted by OP instead of defining a new one. Secondly, It is a Doubly Linked List, not Singly.

Comment: I fixed it my friend

Comment: Some important observations from my side. OP is using `tail` pointer in the code. Also, OP already has similar functionality defined in `append()`. Please refer to code for more info.